Simple in-memory database with persistence in one file
I'm looking for an in-memory database, where I will keep a long list of records.

Each record will have a variable number of non-unique (!) attributes (similar to how NoSQL tables are organized).
I need to be able to save it from memory to disc and backwards, preferably having everything in a single file.
The speed is what matters for me.
No parallelism is required: the file will be loaded by the database engine into memory, modified, and then saved to another file.
The size of the database will be up to 100Mb and up to 10K records.
There will be mostly SELECT queries (heavily relying on indexes), UPDATEs, and INSERTs (no DELETEs)
No journaling or ACID transactions are needed.
The speed of loading the data into memory and saving it back to the disc doesn't matter at all.

What software would you recommend using?

The file will be used only by one application at a time, right? Not by several apps in parallel? What size of data? What kind of queries will you perform? Is JSON deserialization+serialization too slow? Do you need journaling (changes safe even in case of computer crash)?

@NicolasRaoul thanks for the comment, I updated the question

Is it OK to be slow the first time (when loading the file to memory), then fast afterwards for the SELECTs?

@NicolasRaoul I updated the question again

Sorry another question: What programming language is your app written in?

@NicolasRaoul my app is in Ruby, but I can easily make a bridge to C/C++, Rust, or any other compilable low-level language

I would take a look at SQLite. I believe it meets all your requirements.

I doesn't seems to meet the first point of variable number of columns.

Wouldn’t a JSON column type support this? Which is similar to NoSQL.

JSON will work for storage, but won't allow searching by its fields

Have you looked at its JSON functions and operators? They allow you to manipulate the JSON data as well as filtering the JSON data by its fields.
